# What does this vertical line notation mean?

Tags: classical-mechanics, differentiation, notation, mathematics, calculus

Here is the definition of the Noether momentum in my script.

$$I = \left.\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}} \frac{d x}{d \alpha} \right|_{\alpha=0} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}} = m \dot{x} = p_x.$$
But I don't understand exactly what this vertical line with $\alpha=0$ means, I would have interpreted it as $\frac{dx}{d0}$ now.

Comment: Well it is not really different from the notation $f^\prime\vert_{x=0}$, for a function $f:\mathbb R\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ and means that you perform the derivative of $f$ and evaluate it at $0$.

Comment: @TobiasFünke Please don't put answers in comments.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano You're right. But I did not want to expand this further and hoped someone else will do so in an answer, which actually just happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means "compute the previous expression and, after that, set $\alpha = 0$". So you will compute the derivative with respect to $\alpha$, and only then plug $\alpha = 0$.

Let $f = f(x)$. These two mean the same thing:
$$\left.\frac{df}{dx}\right|_{x=0} = f'(0).$$
Sometimes the bar notation just happens to be convenient.